# Blanks Cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I got a sheet that came from a query (get external data), but this sheet have many "empty" cells. I put this way, "empty", because when I gave the command to put all empty cells equals zero, a lot of cells, aparentment empty, did not turn into zero. The Excel did not recognize these cells as empty cells, although do not have anything into.

Can anyone knows what kind of magic is envolved in this?

Thanks!

Comment: manually checek the cell. It's possible that while it appears empty, there is an empty ` ` `(space)` character or a carriage return or something in the cell that is not visible to the eye af first glance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some unprintable char. Add a module with this sub:

```
Sub show_content()
    cont = Selection.Value
    If cont <> "" Then
        MsgBox Asc(cont)
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell really is a blank!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, select the seemingly blank cell and run 'show_content' on the macro menu (alt+F8). It will show you the ASCII value of the strange char, if it is not a blank, or confirm it is really a blank (empty cell).

This one will erase cells with blank spaces, so they will become really empty and be recognized as zero by the formulas:

```
Sub erase_spaces()
    For Each elem In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        elem.Value = Trim(elem.Value)
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Comment: I did File>Options>Advanced>Show a zero in cell that have zero value a lot of cells which were in blank turned into zero value ("0"), but some few do not turn. And my problem is that. I made a formula to sum a line when find a specific word, made it in vba, but i got error when my conter find this cells (cells in blank apparently). I run this code that you write above, and said to me that one of this cells blank had a value equal 32, but do not have anything!

How can i solve this?

Comment: 32 is the ASCII value of the blank space. So, the external data is giving you blank spaces, not empty strings. I'll edit my answer to include a way to get rid of these.

Answer (score 0):

Upon finding the character(s) in the cell that appears blank, you can run a "Find and Replace" (`Ctrl+F`) to change all cells with the certain character(s) to "0".

Enter the character(s) in the "Find What" input box and a "0" in the "Replace With" input box.  This will allow you to find and replace all cells that contain the character(s) with a "0" or whatever you would like.

Comment: I did that too, but as I said, Excel does not recognize these blanks cells as empty cells, because of that I cannot replace. When I do what Eduardo Poço said, I got a return of "32", but I cannot see this values, I do not know where this came from!

Comment: This will likely provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank