# Delete row if cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in my worksheet;Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 allows user to enter file location and then ask the latter to select a range and then import data onto sheet2. However, there are 2 blank cells (that could obviously be removed manually) but I'm trying to automate the process but the code below tells me no cells have been found.

```
Sum DeleteRows()
Dim SrchNom
Dim Tb as Range

'we get sheet on which data has been copied

Set Tb = Sheet1.Range("E9")

Set SrchNom = Worksheets(Tb.Value).Range("J1", Worksheets(Tb.Value).Range("J1048576").End(xlUp))

SrchNom.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End sub
```

I want to be able to delete entire row if one cell in column J of sheet Tb is blank. How do I modify this code to be able to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: They are probably not blank, perhaps there are spaces or hidden characters.

Comment: You are right. If on the excel sheet, i type IF(ISBLANK(J2);"ok","ko"), it's telling me the cell is not blank. Any idea on how to remove such cells from my sheet via vba?

Comment: What does `=len(j2)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Worksheets(Sheets(1).Cells(9, 5).Value).Columns("J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

If you may encounter blank cells aren't actually blank due to newline, spaces or a combination you might find the answer given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank) question interesting.

Might this be the case, also know you can iterate backwards through a range deleting all rows in which column J might meet certain conditions, possibly `Chr(10)` or `Chr(32)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, just replace (.Rows(row)) with your range

```
Public Sub deleteRows()

Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim row As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wks = Excel.ActiveSheet
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

With wks
    For row = 1 To lastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(row)) = 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Rows(row)
            Else
                Set rng = Excel.Union(rng, .Rows(row))
            End If
        End If
    Next row
End With

'In order to avoid Run-time error check if [rng] range is not empty, before removing it.
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Call rng.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End Sub
```