# How to delete a row if certain cells are blank in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete an entire row if cells between a certain range are all blank.

For example, for the range B6-H10, if the values from B6-H6 are blank, then delete row 6. It is worth noting that Column A will be populated for the entirety of the range.

At present, the following error is being returned:

'Cannot use that command on overlapping sections'

I believe this error occurs as a result of a value being present within one of the cells within the given range.

The code at present can be found below:-

```
  Public Sub DeleteERows()

  Dim rng As Range

  Set rng = Range("B6:H10")

  rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select
  rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

  End Sub
```

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347053/delete-row-if-cell-is-blank

Comment: Please search Stackoverlow there are many more posts similar to yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379673/excel-vba-delete-empty-rows

Comment: Tyoe `delete blank cells stackoverflow` in google and see how many resutls you get.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways really, but let me start by assuring you, what you really want to do is [avoid `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Instead, try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelRows()

Dim X As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Your sheetname goes here
    For X = 10 To 6 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(X, 2), .Cells(X, 8))) = 0 Then
            .Rows(X).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```