# VBA specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants) count returns 2 when no constants are present

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA (and programming in general) and managed to solve a lot of bugs with your helpful posts and replies. However I am totally stuck now and couldn't find a post about the specific issue I'm facing.

I want to retrieve a count of cells in specified area which contain feedback (mix of text and numbers), and if count equals 0 then file must be moved and renamed. 
The issue is that count in VBA returns 2 where all cells are clearly empty (and the GoTo special cells constants returns 0 in excel).

I have tried Is Empty, Is Blank and special cells for getting the empty cells. I can't get anything to work. I'd be very grateful for suggestions and corrections!

Where did I go wrong?

```
Dim wb As Workbook       
Dim FBrange As Range
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myPath & FileName)
Set FBrange = wb.Sheets(1).Range("N2:N500")


'First convert range to text and remove any text qualifier

 On Error Resume Next 

 Selection.TextToColumns _
     Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
     TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
     Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False,
 Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True 


'Then check for feedback in comments section

On Error Resume Next 

CountConstantsFBrange = FBrange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
If CountConstantsFBrange = 0 Then
    wb.Close
    SaveChanges:=False Name myPath & FileNameFB As MoveTo & _
    "No_Feedback_" & FileNameFB
    GoTo NextFile
End If
```

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank) - it's possible you have characters in your cells that need cleaning out e.g. using `trim()`

Comment: where is `FBrange` defined?

Comment: What about telling VBA what you understand to be a *constant* by narrowing definition e.g. to textvalues and numbers only, i.e. via `CountConstantsFBrange = FBRange.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, XlSpecialCellsValue.xlNumbers + XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues).Count`

Comment: I've added the FBrange details and tried the suggested adjustment, but vba still returns 2 where cells are completely empty.

Comment: Check for  blanks `" "` in your range sequence; even a <kbd>Alt+Ctrl</kbd> used for multiline entries isn't regarded as empty.

Comment: After going through the post @AlexP suggested, I still got nowhere. However, adding a line to set the CountConstantsFBrange to zero before counting, solved it. I'm looping through all files in a folder and performing the same check on each, but apparently need to learn more about how to set variables properly.

Comment: Note that `On Error Resume Next` hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` so if you use it you cannot see your errors, if you don't see them you don't see what is going wrong and you cannot fix it.