# VBA: Issue with checking if next cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on reading some data that is organized like this:
(interpret | as cell divisions)
Attribute | Value | Units | [empty] | Attribute | Value | Units | [empty]...
I'm putting this data into a collection, then printing the collection at the end of the Sub.

Some background:
There aren't always units, but I want them concatenated to the value if they exist.
There also aren't always values, and when this happens I want to skip to the next attribute, not recording the attribute with no value.

```
Dim coll As New Collection
While j <= FinalColumn
    'Check if the attribute actually has a value
    If Len(Cells(row, (j + 1)).Value) <> 0 Then
        coll.Add Cells(row, j).Value 'add attribute

        Dim val As Variant
        If Len(Cells(row, (j + 2)).Value) <> 0 Then
            val = Cells(row, (j + 1)).Value & " " & Cells(row, j + 2).Value 'add value with units
        Else
            val = Cells(row, (j + 1)).Value 'add just the value if there are no units
        End If

        coll.Add val 'add value to collection
    End If
    j = j + 4 'move on to next attribute
Wend
```

I expect the printed lines to look like this:

[Attribute]

[Value]

[Attribute]

[Value]

...

but instead, I'm getting something like this:

[Attribute]

[Value]

[Attribute]

(*whitespace*)

[Attribute]

[Value]

(*whitespace*)

[Attribute]

...

Notice the whitespace? It looks like it has something to do with adding something to the collection when the value doesn't exist, but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank

Comment: `j = j + 4` shouldn't that be `j = j + 2` since your attributes are 2 apart?

Comment: @Cyril The attributes in the spreadsheet are 4 cells apart (see the top part of the post with the | |)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always a good idea to include `Trim()` when checking for entries:

```
Dim coll As New Collection, v , u, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

While j <= FinalColumn
    v = Trim(ws.Cells(row, j + 1).Value)
    u = Trim(ws.Cells(row, j + 2).Value)
    'Check if the attribute actually has a value/unit
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        coll.Add ws.Cells(row, j).Value 'add attribute
        If Len(u) > 0 Then v = v & " " & u
        coll.Add v 'add value to collection
    End If

    j = j + 4 'move on to next attribute
Wend
```