# Excel 2019: CountA is counting empty cells in data imported from CSV

Tags: excel, csv, is-empty

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 and from Office 2007 to 2019. Today, I imported a CSV file into Excel:

```
Data > From Text/CSV > Load
```

The wizard indicated the "File Origin" as "1200: Unicode" and the delimiter as comma. The file does have comma delimiters with double quotes around text.

There was an immediate visual difference from Excel 2007 -- The imported data had table formatting added to it automatically. It was pretty, but I didn't want it, and I found out how to get rid of it by going to "Table Design", unchecking "Header Row" and "Banded Rows" and clicking "Convert to Range" (upon which "Table Design" disappeared from the main menu), and then deleting row 1, which had been added for the unwanted header row. If someone can say how to import the data without the table formatting being added, I'd like to know that, although there's a more important problem.

As in Excel 2007, a connection was set to the CSV file. I don't need that, so I deleted it, as I always have done in Excel 2007.

Now here's the big problem. The entire rectangular range of cells bounded by the number of rows and columns imported is now treated as if every cell has data in it, including those that are empty. This is the case even for rows in which the CSV file has only one data element (i.e., no commas outside of double quotes), so only column A should have data for those rows. When I say that the empty cells are treated as if they have data, what I mean is:

- len(`<cell>`) = 0 (meaning that the cell is empty)
- CountA(`<cell>`) = 1 (meaning that Excel thinks it is not empty)
- CountBlank(`<cell>`) = 1 (meaning that Excel schizophrenically also thinks it is empty)
- Ctrl-arrow skips over these cells along with cells that contain data.
- Sorting A-Z on a column with these cells puts their rows at the top, instead of at the bottom, where they ended up when I did this procedure in Excel 2007.

Edit: Through further testing, I've determined that what is happening is that Excel is incorrectly treating null cells in the import as if they are empty strings.

Is there something I need to do differently when importing the CSV file in Excel 2019 in order to have the empty cells treated correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I can confirm your observations.
- As suggested by @NewSites and confirmed by me, when a CSV file is imported using the current wizard, the blank cells are given a content of a null string `""` (`Value = ""`), whereas when imported using the legacy wizard, the cell remains, indeed, `Empty`
- In addition to what you note, `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` executed over the table range will not find any cells.

3 workarounds

- Use the "Legacy Wizard" for text importing.

  - This does not demonstrate the problem
  - To enable the legacy wizards, navigate to `File > Options > Data` and select the legacy wizards you want. They will then show up as an option on the `Data > Get & Transform Data > Get Data` dropdown.
- Select the blank cells in the table/range and **Del**  (probably best done using VBA code, if you have a lot of cells to select.
- In doing the PowerQuery import, when the wizard opens

  - Select `Transform Data`
  - Replace Values

    - Value to Find:  leave this blank, empty
    - Replace with:  null  *(yes typed just like that.  It is a "keyword")*
    - Then Close and Load the file

Comment: As noted in my edit to my question, I think the explanation is that Excel is incorrectly treating imported nulls as empty strings. I think we can call this a bug.

Comment: The Legacy Wizard solves both problems: It imports null cells correctly and it also does the import without unwanted table formatting. So this is an excellent solution.

Comment: @NewSites Glad to help. And yes, those cells do contain a `""` (null string) when imported via the current Data wizard, and they are `Empty` when imported via the legacy wizard.  I will add that to my answer.

Comment: The Select + Del method is a workaround that I found before you showed me the Legacy Wizard, which is a better solution. I found that method with detailed instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15995214/5803910 , which is an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank , but not the accepted answer. It's a technique worth knowing for other situations.

Comment: @NewSites I edited my answer to show how to manipulate PQ to remove the null strings.  You have to replace the blanks with `null` which, in PQ, will result in an empty cell being transferred to Excel.  It seems that in `PQ` blanks are Excel null strings, and nulls are empty.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for me. I did the "Replace Values" that you instructed, and the cells that are supposed to be empty still behave as empty strings. I also tried "Advanced Options > Match entire cell contents" and still got the same results.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term "Power Query" that you used, so I looked it up and edited your answer to add a link to the MS documentation on it.

Comment: @NewSites Hmmm.  After you did the `Replace`, did you see *null* (right-justified **and** in italics) in the table?

Comment: My edit to link your answer to documentation on Power Query seems to have been rejected. The doc is at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605 .

Comment: @NewSites It was not rejected by me.  But there is a reluctance to include links in Answers that refer to sites outside SO, as their permanence is not guaranteed.

Comment: I'd sure like to try to understand why the PQ fix didn't work. Could you explain more what you did and what happened/didn't happen?

Comment: Re replacing with null, after closing the "Replace Values" dialog, I don't see "null" again anywhere. Under "Query Settings", the "Applied Steps", which before had "Source" and "Change Type", now also have "Replaced Value". If I double-click on that, I get the dialog box again with "Replace With" being "null". I close that and click "Close & Load" and I get the data imported as a formatted table with cells that should be empty behaving as empty strings. As I said, I don't see "null" anywhere, but I'm not sure I'm looking where you want me to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197455/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-newsites).

Comment: Result of that chat: I didn't know I was supposed to select all the columns before doing "Replace Values". When I did that, the empty cells imported as actually empty. However, I still like the legacy wizard better because it doesn't involuntarily turn my CSV data into an Excel table. Thanks Ron, I learned a lot here.