# Unable to format rule for cell to be filled with white when cells have an existing format that generates either blank or value

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the rule format on my cells whereby it will fill the colour based on more than or less than 0 value and the cells are using the format =IF(OR(ISBLANK(P:P),ISBLANK(Q:Q)),"",(P:P-Q:Q)) to generate a value if any else blank.
However when I set a rule to fill it white if blank, it seems to not recognise the cells as blank.

I selected the whole R column and created a conditional format rule of format cells only if blank, and I selected it to be filled with white
However as I currently have 2 other rules where I select the whole R column as well, based on the calculation format of each individual R cell aside from the header column, it will generate a positive or negative number and if >0, it will be in green for both text and background, if <0 it will be in red for both text and background.
So currently, all the cells that has the calculation formula are highlighted green including header column as there's only 2 cells with positive values whilst the rest are blank.

How do I derive a solution to not have blank cells coloured and also maintain the calculation formula.

[Excel telling me my blank cells aren't blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984580/excel-telling-me-my-blank-cells-arent-blank)
I have looked through the answers in this thread but it's not working either

Comment: ISBLANK will only return true if it is truly blank, ie no formula or sound value.  If there is a formula that returns a `""` then it will return FALSE.  Also you should do: `=IF((P:P="")+(Q:Q="")),"",P:P-Q:Q)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and additional solution, so I take it as there's no way to fill my blank formulated cells with a colour of my choice?

Comment: we will need more information to properly answer that.  Please include a [mcve]

Comment: My plan is using the formula, if true, the cell would be blank so I am trying to set a rule to format to white since if any of P or Q is blank, the resulting cell will be blank.
Else, if negative the value and cell will be filled red, if positive the value and cell will be filled green

Apologies, hope it's sufficient info

Comment: please [edit] the post with any clarification to include the [mcve].  There is no where in your post you describe that you wanted to use the formula to change the color.  The formula rule in conditional formatting should return TRUE/FALSE not a number or blank.  Also you would not refer to the full column but the top cell in the applies to range.  Please show your full approach to the conditional format rules.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post, hopefully it meets the criteria, sorry about that.

Comment: The formula you should use is: `=OR(P1="",Q1="")` for your blank white.

Comment: I used =OR($P:$P="",$Q:$Q="") in formula rule but it just turned the whole column white and removed the borders

Comment: I did not say use: `=OR($P:$P="",$Q:$Q="")`  I said `=OR(P1="",Q1="")`

Comment: Okay I've retried and it worked now, earlier nothing was changed so I tried =OR($P:$P="",$Q:$Q=""). Thanks